# searching presence of words in different lines in a set of lines. c# windows form

Tags: c#, string, search

So I'm working on a text mining project and currently trying to implement info gain. I have a data in which each line depict a document. so a new line character splits different documents.

I have to generate a matrix in which columns are all the distinct words in all documents and rows are different document. each cell in this table is either 1(true) or 0(false) for if the word is present or not in that document.

Note: i have removed all repeated words in a document already.

```
 class word_list
 {
     public string word;
     public List<bool> doc = new List<bool>();
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Convert the string into an array of words 
     string[] w1 = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n', ' ').Select(x => x.Trim().ToLower()).Distinct().ToArray();
     string[] rich_doc = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
     List<word_list> words = new List<word_list>();
     word_list temp = new word_list();
     for (int i = 0; i < w1.Length; i++)
     {
         temp.word = w1[i];

         for (int j = 0; j < rich_doc.Length; j++)//all doc array
         {
             List<string> doc_word = Regex.Split(rich_doc[j], @"\b").Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
             for (int k = 0; k < doc_word.Count; k++)//All words in a doc 
             {
                 if (doc_word[k] == w1[i])
                 {
                     temp.doc.Add(true);
                     words.Add(temp);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     temp.doc.Add(false);
                     words.Add(temp);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     //generate matrix
     int t = rich_doc.Length; //no. of docs
     string final_matrix = "Doc number";
     for (int i = 0; i < words[0].doc.Count; i++)
     {
         final_matrix += "\t" + words[i].word;
     }
     final_matrix += "\n";

     for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) //traverse through number of docs
     {
         final_matrix += i + 1;
         for (int h = 0; h < words.Count; h++)//traverse through each distinct word in the list
         {
             if (words[h].doc[t])
                 final_matrix += "\t1";
             else
                 final_matrix += "\t0";
         }
         final_matrix += "\n";
     }
     richTextBox1.Text = final_matrix;
 }//end of button 2
```

The problem is that this code is running in an infinite loop.

Comment: Is this an assignment?  Is there anything you can't use (like Regex)?  I think you could simplify it a lot

Comment: I only see a way to provoke an infinite loop with your code: while affecting the class word_list (whose code you didn't post). Other than that, the only way to provoke an infinite loop in your code would be by modifying the variables defining the loop (e.g., the one being iterated or the maximum one) inside the loop itself, what is not happening anywhere. Can you please post the definition of word_list?

Comment: i have posted the whole definition of word_list. am using that class like a structure

Comment: can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: PS: if you don't write @my_nick and we are not in a question/answer posted by me, I might get your messages or not (in this case, I didn't get it)

Comment: @varocarbas i have to generate a matrix in the richtextbox1. i have written all the details above in the question already. this is the sample data http://www.mediafire.com/?4mojnj4j153q76s.

Comment: @Jonesy yes i can use anything that helps

Comment: @varocarbas ok lets just forget this code for a while. can you make a code for this.

Comment: ... but I guess that I am not the best person to help you (I am not here to re-write codes). Sorry for the misunderstanding and good luck with your help search. I recommend you to put more effort in clarity and communication aspects (will delete some of comments because are pointless).

Comment: Yes, I got that. But the only help I can give you is redoing everything and from our conversation (we have some communication problems), this does not sound too right. As far as the whole point is communicating the idea (and it has been proven that I am quite bad at that, now and with you). As said, better wait for other helper; one understanding your code/requirements better and quicker :)

Comment: Try to identify which for loop is the problematic one, then analyze that one in detail. Without having access to code, it is not trivial to find an answer.